# Vertexquads are not being drawn in 2D space

Tags: c++, 2d, graphics, directx11

I started teaching myself DirectX a short time ago and have come across a problem which I can't figure out by myself unfortunately.
I'm trying to build my own font system, so I can draw strings in 2D screenspace. Until now Until now I have managed to create a function to which I just have to pass the string and the screenspace-positions., and it generates all vertices for / sets up the buffers etc (quads that i draw a certain portion of the font texture on). 
When I draw these vertices in 3D space, everything looks like it works like it should be.
[image: Text in 3D space]

(Forgot to hide the cube) As soon as I try to switch to 2D, I just get a window filled with the blue backgroundcolor. To switch to 2D I do the following things:

```
graphics.context->ClearDepthStencilView(graphics.depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
context->OMSetDepthStencilState(depthDisabledStencilState, 1);

WVP = XMMatrixOrthographicLH((float)mWidth, (float)mHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
cbPerVert.WVP = XMMatrixTranspose(WVP);
cbPerVert.World = XMMatrixTranspose(World);

context->UpdateSubresource( cbPerVertexBuffer, 0, NULL, &cbPerVert, 0, 0 );
context->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &cbPerVertexBuffer );
```

My Question is now what I am doing wrong here. If the vertices are being genrated and drawn correctly, afaik all I have to do is project them into screenspace and disable the depth buffer, which I did here..  BTW: I randomly tried drawing the cube with my 2D settings and it was properly drawn..  Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Your font vertices could be the problem probably, if your cube is drawn correctly. (rough guess: maybe your font vertices are on the XZ plane and your projection projects to the XY plane?)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The font vertices are in the XY-Plane, and for getting the cube drawn correctly in 2D I set the z-componenents of all cube-vertices to 0.

Comment: I doubt anyone would get you anything but guesses with so little information, I suggest you debug your code yourself. (For example you could check your font vertices after the matrix multiplication, or check with a graphics debugger)

Comment: wild guess 2: Maybe you are culling the wrong side of your quads?

Comment: Thanks a whole lot! Today I learned what culling is thansk to you :D Looks like I filled the vertexbuffer in such a way that I was drawing backfaces. Fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, I will write an answer to this post please accept it, so this site could benefit from the question.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was the culling, I recommend to debug your code while turning off the culling with D3D11_CULL_NONE flag in the rasterizer if your geometry does not get displayed, this is quite a common problem for beginners.
And be sure to cull the backfaces in a release application wherever you can.